# Finding the Average Difference in Ability Between Two Teams

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose you have $N$ football players, where $N$ is even, ranked in order of ability by the integers $\{1, \dots, N\}$ (where 1 is the best, N the worst) and they are randomly split into into two teams of $\frac{N}{2}$ players. I want to find the expected difference in the average player quality between the two teams.

For small $N$, I've managed to compute this by considering every case with the following R code:

```
perm = permutations(N,N)
stored = rep(0,factorial(N))
for (i in 1:factorial(N))
{
  team1 = perm[i,1:(N/2)]
  team2 = perm[i,(N/2 + 1):N]
  stored[i] = abs(mean(team1)-mean(team2))
}
mean(stored)
```

For $N \in \{2,4,6,8,10\}$, this yields average differences of 1, 1, $\frac{38}{30}$, $\frac{7}{5}$ and $\frac{14}{9}$. However, I can't go any higher since I reach the storage limits.

How would I go about finding the expected values in general? Is there a closed-form expression depending only on N?

Edit: some better code which can be used for larger values of N:

```
library(gtools)
library(MASS)

temp = combinations(N,N/2)
stored = rep(0,choose(N,N/2))
for (i in 1:choose(N,N/2))
{
  team1 = temp[i,]
  team2 = seq(1,N)[-team1]
  stored[i] = abs(mean(team1)-mean(team2))
}
mean(stored)
```

Comment: I do not see an immediate way to get a closed form. That is one of the reasons why the root mean square difference in ability is a preferred measure.

Comment: Is there a closed form in that case?

Comment: Yes, there is for that measure of difference.

Comment: Would you be able to give me any indication on how to derive it?